# php setting an error log

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

I'm having a hard time forcing my application to log errors.
Here is a file hierarchy:

```
/opt
  +-lampp
      +-htdocs
        +-project
          +-app
          | +-config
          | | +-errors.php
          | +-controllers
          | +-log
          | | +-error.log
          | +-etc...
          | +-index.php
          +-pub
```

And here is the errors.php :

```
<?php
/*
 * This is configuration for error handling
 */

ini_set('safe_mode','off');
//to display errors in browser, set 1
ini_set('display_errors',1);
//to write errors to a  log file, set 1
ini_set('log_errors',1);
//set default file to log errors
ini_set('error_log','app/log/error.log');
//error reporting level, set to E_ALL to see all errors and notices
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ERROR|
        E_WARNING|
        E_CORE_ERROR|
        E_CORE_WARNING|
        E_COMPILE_ERROR|
        E_COMPILE_WARNING|
        E_USER_ERROR|
        E_USER_WARNING|
        E_STRICT|
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|
        E_DEPRECATED|
        E_USER_DEPRECATED);
error_log('hi');
```

I read in some article that this might be caused by the safe mode, so i turned it of, but it changed nothing.

Also have an idea that my path might be wrong, in that case, what should it be?

I realise that this question was asked before, but i have already read these articles and they didn't helped me. Even though this is a kind of a "debug my code" question, could someone help me?

(p.s. im sure the error.php file was reached and executed.)
(p.p.s. error.php is included in index.php)

EDIT:

So i commented the safe mode line and dumped these lines:

error_reporting => int(22527)

error_log       => bool(true)

Comment: the `safe_mode` option CAN NOT be set from within a script. it works only at the .ini level. It's also been completely REMOVED from PHP as of v5.4. Have you checked what the return value of the error_reporting() and error_log() calls is?

Comment: Added it on the edit.

Comment: shoud be absolute path ini_set('error_log','/opt/lamp/htdocs/project/app/log/error.log');

Comment: ok, ill try, but is there any way to do it without absolute path? That would be really helphull (or mabie there's a function to print the absolute path?)

Comment: I don't think it is possible with relative path, but use `__DIR__` is possible so `ini_set('error_log',__DIR__.'/../log/error.log')`;

Comment: echo __DIR__.'/app/log/error.log'; 
echoed:
/opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/app/configuration/app/log/error.log;

how sould i go down the two folders to the project root?

Comment: well, ../ is not an elegant way, but it does the job i guess... thank you again for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the posts, i learned quite a couple of things from them. When i tried the absolute path i learned that the problem is in file rights. All i had to do is

```
sudo chmod 777 error.log
```

Anyway, is it a good idea to have a file with 777 rights in your project directory?

Comment: you don't need 777 if directory group set to your webserver user

Comment: i store files in my personal computer, how should i set up groups to get rid of 777? (lubuntu with casual user in suddoers group, later this will be stored on server)

Comment: Just one last question(not to the topic), whitch user rights must be changed? i mean, what user is doing the error logging on the server?